# i am getting access denied in devcpp on executing any program

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I am getting 
Failed to execute "C:\Users\dell\Documents\code.exe":
Error 5: Access is denied.
whenever i try to execute a file in DecC++ software .
anybody please help me out.

Comment: Not sure about why that happenees, but don't use dev-c++, the project looks dead (not updates since ~2015...).

Comment: then what is alternative

Comment: Alternatives are listed in the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dev-c%2b%2b/info)

Comment: Try to run dev-c++ run as admin/root

Comment: i tried run as admin but still same problem

Comment: With the current information it is impossible to answer your question. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ok i think i solved my problem by now.thanqu guys for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open DEVC++ and there is an option in toolbar next to compile and run of "TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Release" change this to "TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Profiling" and your program will execute.